# Como borrar correctamente mis elementos<li>?

Tags: javascript

Estoy varado en un código. El código consiste en agregar elementos a una lista y después borrar cada elemento ' li ' con solo un click en el mismo. ¿En que estoy fallando? Por ejemplo agrego tres elementos a mi lista, y yo quiero borrar el segundo elemento pero se me borra el primer elemento, quiero borrar el tercer elemento pero se  borra el segundo elemento de la lista. Me he puesto a pensar que no estoy usando bien el siclo for(){}. Aparte de esto en la consola me aparece error.

```js
/*variables*/
let inpText=document.getElementsByName("inp")[0];
let btn=document.getElementsByName("inp")[1]; 
btn.setAttribute("value","add");
let padre=document.getElementById("lista");
let hija=padre.children;

/*funciones*/
Limpiar = () => inpText.value="";

Agregar= () => {
  let x = document.createElement("li");
  x.textContent=inpText.value;
  padre.appendChild(x);
}

Eliminar = () => {
  for(let i=0;i<hija.length;i--){
    padre.removeChild(hija[i]);
  }
}

/*eventos*/

inpText.addEventListener("click",Limpiar);
btn.addEventListener("click",Agregar);
padre.addEventListener("click",Eliminar);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inp" placeholder="agregar items">
<input type="button" name="inp">    
<ul id="lista">
</ul>
```

Comment: Súper... muy buena tu respuesta  sencilla y óptima. Muchas gracias. También estuve cacharreando y encontré otra forma de eliminar los items por ejemplo:         Eliminar=(e)=>{
for(let i=0;i<hija.length;i--){
padre.removeChild(e.target);
}
}            /* lo malo es que en la consola me sigue dando error. Pero el código funciona. Para mi esto es un misterio*/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bueno, corregido tu código.*

*En realidad la forma como estabas eliminando no es la apropiada. Entiendo que deseas eliminar el elemento*

> **< li >**

*que seleccionas. Siendo así he comentado tu funcion Eliminar y en ves de darle la orden al padre, al momento de agregar un elemento le agrego el evento diciendole que al ser presionado lo remueva.*

Te lo dejo para que compares con el tuyo.

```js
/*variables*/
let inpText=document.getElementsByName("inp")[0];
let btn=document.getElementsByName("inp")[1]; 
btn.setAttribute("value","add");
let padre=document.getElementById("lista");
let hija=padre.children;

/*funciones*/
Limpiar = () => inpText.value="";

Agregar= () => {
  let x = document.createElement("li");
  x.textContent=inpText.value;
  // Anexamos el evento que deseamos al elemento.
  x.addEventListener("click", () => {
    x.remove();
  });
  padre.appendChild(x);
}

// No es la forma apropiada
/*Eliminar = () => {
  for(let i=0;i<hija.length;i--){
    padre.removeChild(hija[i]);
  }
}*/

/*eventos*/

inpText.addEventListener("click",Limpiar);
btn.addEventListener("click",Agregar);
// Se comenta dado que el evento se lo dimos al elemento en si que deseamos eliminar en este caso
// padre.addEventListener("click",Eliminar);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inp" placeholder="agregar items">
<input type="button" name="inp">    
<ul id="lista">
</ul>
```

***Como puedes observar, comenté lo siguiente:***

```js
Eliminar = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < hija.length; i--) {
    padre.removeChild(hija[i]);
  }
}

padre.addEventListener("click",Eliminar);
```

***Modifiqué tu método Agregar de la siguiente manera:***

```js
Agregar = () => {
  let x = document.createElement("li");
  x.textContent = inpText.value;
  // Anexamos el evento que deseamos al elemento.
  x.addEventListener("click", () => {
    x.remove();
  });
  padre.appendChild(x);
}
```

*Espero te sirva*

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el error pueda estar en la función Eliminar:

```
Eliminar = () => {
   for(let i=0;i<hija.length;i--){
       padre.removeChild(hija[i]);
   }   
}
```

Si te fijas bien el incrementador del bucle estás haciendo i-- con lo que los valores de i van a ser 0, -1, -2, ... con lo que obtendrás un error al acceder al índice hija[i].